# Keep in-app-purchases downloading when iPhone sleeps

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

I need help on how to keep in-app-purchase items in my application downloading when the user sleeps his iPhone, or the application enter the background mode. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define *BackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler* in **applicationDidEnterBackground:** like this:

```
// ...
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bti;
// ...

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    bti = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if(bti != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
                [application endBackgroundTask:bti];
                bti = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }
        });
    }];
    
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // DO or CONTINUE RESUMED DOWNLOAD HERE
        
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if(bti != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
                [application endBackgroundTask:bti];
                bti = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

To see how it works download [sample project](https://github.com/jacekmigacz/BTWEH) I made for You.

> git clone
> https://github.com/jacekmigacz/BTWEH.git

...and press ***Home Button*** to trigger **applicationDidEnterBackground:**.

Idea is to delegate your download task to another, privileged thread and keep your application in background state instead of let OS suspend it.

Comment: bro in [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:,,,,, should i change APPLICATION to the name of my application here